# Highlight item with mouse hover in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a `QStandardItemModel` that I am displaying as a `QTreeView` with multiple columns. How can I make it highlight rows when the mouse hovers over them?

**Related pages**

- [How to catch mouse over event of QTableWidget item in pyqt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064975/how-to-catch-mouse-over-event-of-qtablewidget-item-in-pyqt):
  similar question using `QTableWidget` instead of `Q*View`.
- [Customizing QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview): suggests it is possible to do it very
  easily with stylesheets, but I don't quite follow the c++.
- [How to highlight the entire row on mouse hover in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111075/how-to-highlight-the-entire-row-on-mouse-hover-in-qtablewidget-qt5)
- [QListView selection with highlight/hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992849/qlistview-selection-with-highlight-hover)

Comment: Doesn't QTreeView highlight items by default on mouse hover?

Comment: @LahiruChandima No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by a stylesheet

```
treeView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:hover{background-color:#FFFF00;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lahiru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28804190/1886357) is easy to translate to PyQt/PySide, as the input to `setStyleSheet` doesn't need any modification: it is the same in Qt/PyQt/PySide:

```
treeView.setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:hover{background-color:#999966;}")
```

I found it helpful to read the [Overview of style sheet syntax for Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html). Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333537/1886357) has some nice examples on using style sheets in PySide/PyQt.